# Getting different output for DataFrame & normal implementation of same code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopy

I'm trying to calculate vincety distance between two points of a DataFrame. If I input strings directly I get following output:

```
loca1 = [12.9404578177, 77.5548244743]
loca2 = [12.9404578177, 77.5548244743]
print vincenty(loca1,loca2).meters 

>>>0.0
```

While implementing same thing with Dataframe I get following output:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty 
for i in range(len(cleandata)):
    if i < 303708:
        location2 = cleandata.iloc[i]['location']
        location1 = cleandata.iloc[i+1]['location']
        cleandata.iloc[i]['distance'] = vincenty(location1, location2).meters
    else:
        print i

print cleandata.loc[1]['distance']
>>>*13921
```

`cleandata['location']` has exactly the same coordinates strings I put in 1st code.
I checked in both cases the variables going into vincety function are lists.

How to explain and fix this strange behaviour?

Comment: Is it because you're printing `loc` and not `iloc`?

Comment: No, iloc is used when you are integers indexthis case 'i' while loc is used when you want to use label index here 'distance'

Answer (score 1):

Well I got my answer, the values 13921 was from previous code which was not getting over written, following change made the overwriting possible

```
cleandata.iloc[i,'distance'] = vincenty(location1, location2).meters
```

instead of `cleandata.iloc[i]['distance']`